# No Suitable Constructor Found

Tags: java

Incredibly new to Java so forgive the simplicity in this issue. I've looked through posts on this issue, but none seem to help. 
This is the error I'm getting; '*no suitable contructor found for AQAWriteTextFile2016(String)*' for the code below.

```
String filename = "src/warships/resources/PreviousGame.txt";  
AQAWriteTextFile2016 write = new AQAWriteTextFile2016(filename);
```

I apologise if the solution is something simple, I've checked through the AQAWriteTextFile2016 class and all it needs to operate is a String parameter.

```
AQAWriteTextFile2016(String filename) {

openFile(filename, false);

}

  public void openFile(String filename, boolean append) {
try {

  outputFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, append));

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} // end try/catch open file
} // end openFileString
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the `AQAWriteTextFile2016 ` class?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add code. It is impossible to read it in a comment.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Relevant branches of the AQA Class are in the post now, will look into those examples now

Comment: Does the constructor `AQAWriteTextFile2016` have any visibility (public/private) modifier? If it doesn't, it means it is package protected, and if it is defined in different package as your class, then you can't use it.

Comment: @Radoh the class has a public modifier

Comment: @RoxelGraphics I wasn't asking about class modifier, but constructor modifier. But I see Barth already answered, upvoted

Answer (score 3):

From the snippet in your code, we see that the constructor has no access specifier. So it has the default visibility, which is package-private. It can only be seen from within the same package.

If the call to the constructor is made from a different package, then it cannot be seen from there.

Hence, you should make the constructor `public`, or make the call from within the same package.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that what you think as the constructor with String argument is actually a method having name `AQAWriteTextFile2016`. Please look closely at the return type.  A constructor should not have any return type. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't believe the `AQAWriteTextFile2016` method returns anything, the code for that class is included in the post now